# Custom Map in Android Application

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Ok, so I am going to do my best to convey exactly what I am looking to accomplish. I have thus far completed some minor Java courses at school and working on some android tutorials.

I have access to a google map that has consistently updated information regarding conditions in an area. Is it possible for me to write a program  that shows the map on this link and stays current? Can this be done without the use of webview? Or is that link going to be dynamic and change as the overlay does? Would it be possible to instead call upon the website then to utilize that specific area of the webpage that has the map?

https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zEDHoFPoYHv4.kHYurQFY7s8s&hl=en

I am doing this all for self educational purposes, not looking to create anything commercial, other wise I realize I would likely want to contact the host and ask them for permission to use their data.

I've read through several of the Google Maps API information, but I can not find anything specifically that states I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

By "have access to a map", do you mean that you have access to the map tiles? If so, you can [add a TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay) to a base Google Map, which will download the tiles from your server.